# Doubly Circular Linked list GetData method

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

anyone can help me? y cannot get data `result = temp.data` below is my statement

```
public T getEntry(int givenPosition) {
    T result = null;
    if(root ==null)
        return null;
    else{
         DNode temp = root;

         for(int i=0;i<givenPosition;i++){
             //if(temp !=root.nextNode){
                 temp = temp.nextDNode;
                 //lala = temp.data;
             // }
         }
         result = temp.data;
    }
    return result;
}

public class DNode <T> {

    T data;
    DNode nextDNode;
    DNode previousDNode;

    DNode(T data){

        this.data = data;
        numberOfEntries++;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Is it a runtime or compiler error? As a side-note: if you share code, please format it properly...

Comment: no is cannot run... i am newbie for this website...the error is Object cannot be converted to T

Comment: You need a DNode<T> everywhere, not just DNode. If you don't use the type variable, then it essentially defaults T to be Object.

Answer (score 2):

Try make `temp` using `T`, i.e `DNode<T> temp = root;`